# no data recieved by recv() for https request in c++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am a newbie in Socket Programming. I am trying to create a socket to a HTTPS website. The socket is created successfuuly and i am able to connect using and send the header... But as a response from recv() i am getting no header response neither i am getting -1... the program is just blocked there... The site has open port 443 for https...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netdb.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int status;
    struct addrinfo hostInfo;
    struct addrinfo *hostList;
    memset(&hostInfo, 0, sizeof(hostInfo));
    hostInfo.ai_family = AF_INET;     
      hostInfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    cout<<"Setting up the structs..."<<endl;
    status = getaddrinfo("academics.vit.ac.in", "https", &hostInfo, &hostList);
    if(status == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Success"<<endl;
        //cout<<hostList->ai_addr<<" "<<hostList->ai_socktype;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Failled!";
    }
    int socketd;
    socketd = socket(hostList->ai_family, hostList->ai_socktype, hostList->ai_protocol);
    if(socketd == -1)
    {
        cout<<"Socket Error\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Socket Success\n";
    }
    cout<<"Connecting\n";
    status = connect(socketd, hostList->ai_addr, hostList->ai_addrlen);
    if(status == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Success"<<endl;
        //cout<<hostList->ai_addr<<" "<<hostList->ai_socktype;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Failled!";
    }
    cout<<"\nSending Header\n";
    char *msg = "GET /student/stud_login.asp HTTP/1.1\nhost: academics.vit.ac.in\nConnection: keep-alive\nCache-Control: max-age=0\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36\nReferer: https://academics.vit.ac.in/\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\nCookie: ASPSESSIONIDAWRSBBBS=HJBNNABBBAIADHKAGEFLELJK; ASPSESSIONIDCUTRADBT=GNMNDGBBFDJHBLHABHDGCCOO; ASPSESSIONIDCUQTABAT=IOAAMMNBACANEDJFMGMLMNJA; ASPSESSIONIDAUSQBCAS=GBNFBCOBEKIOJJHFPMJNMJII\n\n";
cout<<"\n"<<msg<<endl;
    int len = strlen(msg);
    ssize_t msgSize;
    msgSize = send(socketd, msg, len, 0);
    if(msgSize == len)
    {
        cout<<"Sending Header Successful\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error Sending Header\n";
    }
    cout<<"Waiting to recieve data\n";
    char rmsg[1000];
    msgSize  = recv(socketd, rmsg, 10, 0);
    cout<<msgSize<<rmsg<<endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are writing to a server port that expects SSL protocol and sending plain text.  You need to use an appropriate library to perform the protocol handshake and encryption.

Comment: I believe the standard practice is to use openssl libraries for this purpose.

Comment: So does it mean that i cannot directly send the header for https request?

Comment: Did you consider using, or at least studying the source code of, some free software HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (and possibly also a server HTTP library like e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) etc...)?

Comment: SSL is not going to let you send whatever plaintext header you want. Like @JimGarrison said, you need to follow the correct protocol in order to get the server to serve you.

Comment: @AbhishekBatra - If the server is expecting SSL it will most definitely ignore anything you send that does not conform to the SSL handshake protocol.  You cannot send plain text to an SSL port; the server will just close the connection.  Study the openssl library and API, and find an SSL tutorial on the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

You should set your socket to nonblocking (using fnctl()) and then see what recv() returns. 
Check errno as well. That should give you more information.

See man 2 recv() @ http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv.

Comment: the error i am getting is "Resource temporarily unavailable"... bt the  same thing works when in the function getaddrinfo i change "https" to "80"